# How to adjust button sizes according to screen resolutions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want o adjust button sizes according to screen resolutions,on smaller devices screens as on well as on PC screen

Comment: Do you specifically need the <button> tag or even anchors will work ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work?rq=1

Comment: PLease view my posted answer and accept it as answer for close this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275323/how-to-make-trialngular-shaped-button-in-css/18275451#18275451 ThanQ :)

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct, but they are not **equilateral** like the OP requests. Try this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/mt2yA/

```
<a href='#'>
  <div class='tri-button'></div>
</a>

.tri-button {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 80px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href='#'>
  <div class='tri-button'></div>
</a>

.tri-button {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid black;
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/brbcoding/pen/DoGbA)**

Answer (score 1):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ makes it extremely simple.

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;

    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

    border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [JSBin with equilateral triangle](http://jsbin.com/irenen/6/edit)

```
<a href='#'>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</a>
```

In your CSS

```
.triangle {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I would have to do this I suppose that the best way is mapping an image. You have to do a simple image with triangle shape and transparent background and then using a map you could define an area with this shape (only with three coordinates). You can add a href attribute to the area and use it as a link.

```
<img src="triangle.png" usemap="#mapa" width="100" height="100"/>
<map name="mapa">
<area shape="poly" coords="0,100,50,0,100,100,0,100" href="">
```

You would be generating a button with triangle shape. You can add to this area some functions of js if you want too.